# Shopify: Filter by Multiple Tags at Same time

Tags: shopify, liquid

Ok so I am creating menu for filtering products in order to keep my tags and submenu from being extremely long.

I have created a dropdown filter for my main categories (I have added an unless to eliminate sub-level category tags)

I then have a sub-category menu that only shows when "All Categories" isn't selected.

This then generates a sub-category filter for all tags in that category.  See below for code:

```
<div class="text-center">
<div class="browseby" style="display:inline;padding:20px;">
    <div class="clearfix filter" style="float:left;">
       Browse By Category <select class="coll-filter">
         <option value="">All</option>
         {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
             {% unless tag == 'HP' or tag == 'Latex' or tag == 'Latex 570' or tag == 'Parts' or tag == 'Aqueous Media' or tag == 'Latex Media' or tag == 'Solvent Media' %}  
                 {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                    <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }} ({{ collection.products_count }})</option>
                 {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
                 {% endif %}
             {% endunless %}
         {% endfor %}
       </select>
    </div>
    {% if current_tags %}
        <div class="clearfix filter" style="float:left; padding-left:20px">

            Browse By Sub-Category <select class="coll-filter">
             <option value="">All</option>
             {% for tag in collection.tags %}
                {% unless current_tags contains tag  %}  
                    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                        <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }} ({{ collection.products_count }})</option>
                    {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endunless %}
             {% endfor %}



           </select>
        </div>
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Now the problem is when I select the sub-category filter the tag isn't shown as selected.

Browse By Category shows All and then inside the dropdown I have (All, Category1, Category2, Category3..)
If i selected Category3 the page reloads and shows Browse By Category: Category3

Browse By Sub-Category shows All and then inside the dropdown I have (All, SubMenu1, SubMenu2, SubMenu3)
If I select SubMenu2 the products all filter.
Browse By Category still shows: Category3
But Browse By Sub-Category shows: All
Inside the dropdown menu I have (All, SubMenu1, SubMenu3) <-- The category that is being filtered disappears from the list, but does filter products.

If this is confusing let me know.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!!

I found the problem in the above code. The {% unless %} tag in the second filter was causing the problem. The unless was to filter out the main category filter but ended up making the selected option not available. I made my Main Categories start with cat- and the sub-level categories start with sub-

Now the code works mostly... Still having issues when using the sub-category and then filtering back to a main category. The URL keeps the sub-cat and just adds a new main category...

Anyway for those that are interested here is my new code:

```
<div class="text-center">
<div class="browseby" style="display:inline;padding:20px;">
    <div class="clearfix filter" style="float:left;">
       Browse By Category <select class="coll-filter">
         <option value="">All</option>
         {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
            {% if tag contains 'cat-' %}
             {% assign tagName = tag | remove: 'cat-' %}         
              {% if current_tags contains tag %}
              <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tagName }}</option>
              {% else %}
              <option value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tagName }}</option>
              {% endif %}                     
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
       </select>
    </div>

        <div class="clearfix filter" style="float:left; padding-left:20px">

            Browse By Type: <select class="coll-filter">
             <option value="">All</option>
             {% for tag in collection.tags %}

                {% if tag contains 'sub-' %}
                 {% assign tagName = tag | remove: 'sub-' %}         
                  {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                  <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tagName }}</option>
                  {% else %}
                  <option value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tagName }}</option>
                  {% endif %}                     
                {% endif %}

              {% endfor %}



           </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the link of the store where you've implemented this?